# generating number from 1 to 6 with given probability give me number from 1 to 7

Tags: matlab, math, random, probability, cumsum

As I see in the other post, about generating random numbers with given probability, I've found this useful code that I've used in my program :

```
r = rand;
prob = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4];
x = sum(r >= cumsum([0, prob]));
disp(x)

it gives

0.5 chance of 1
0.1 chance of 2
0.4 chance of 3
```

I've adapted this exemple to my needs: I need to generate  number from 1 to 6 with the following proba :

```
signal5=[0.233  0.233   0.233 0.1    0.1     0.1   ];
```

until now, all is perfect.

When I try to verify results with big number of trial (1000) I've a strange one case or two where x=7 :

```
k=1
for k=1:1000
signal5=[0.233  0.233   0.233 0.1    0.1     0.1   ];
r = rand;
            x = sum(r >= cumsum([0, eval('signal5')]));
 fid=fopen('seed.txt','a+');
 fprintf(fid,'Trial  %s  X %s',num2str(k),num2str(x));
 fclose(fid);
k=k+1
end
```

Why I've sometimes 7 for a big number of trial?

Comment: Hint: what's the sum of the values in `signal5`?  (It's not 1.0.)  Quick fix: just throw out the last entry in `signal5`.

Comment: I should go over that 4 numbers after the comma , I've tried with 5, As simple as that, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a side note before we start: Have you looked at the `randsample` function?  This also allows you to draw values from a distribution where each value is encountered with a certain probability.  BTW, you don't need the `eval` statement there.  It's superfluous.  Just reference the variable instead (`signal5`).

Now to get onto your question.  When you are doing this statement:

```
x = sum(r >= cumsum([0, eval('signal5')]));
```

What is happening is that you will get a 7th entry because there may be a time where you generate a random number of `1.0` when the total sum of your probabilities is `0.99`.  What will inevitably happen is that when you do `cumsum`, it gets "pushed" over to the next bin which is why there is a 7th occurrence.  As what @MarkDickenson has suggested, a quick fix is to throw out the 7th value.  Another fix that I could suggest would be to slightly change one of the probabilities in the beginning of your vector so that it is increased by `0.001`.  That way all of your probabilities sum to 1.  For example, do something like:

```
signal5=[0.234  0.233   0.233 0.1    0.1     0.1   ];
```

The significance of the `0.001` offset will (hopefully!) be negligible.